# carrierwave-aws: Rails API app file upload fails with NoMethodError - undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass

Tags: aws-sdk, carrierwave

Hitting quite the wall on this issue. Let me explain what i've done and show the snippets of configured code, to hopefully find a solution

```
Ruby: 2.4.0
Rails: 5.x
Gems (specific to this): 
 - carrierwave 1.2.3
 - carrierwave-aws
```

Here is the error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass:
  app/controllers/api/v3/video_controller.rb:23:in `upload'
```

Here is my config/environments/carrierwave.rb file

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage :aws
  config.aws_credentials = {
    provider:              "AWS",
    aws_access_key_id:     Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_id,
    aws_secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_secret,
    region:                "us-east-1"
  }
  config.aws_bucket = "{{BUCKET_NAME_HERE}}"
end
```

Here is my uploader

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :aws
end
```

Finally, here is how i'm calling the upload, since it's an API, i'm not using a form builder or model assignment.

```
def upload
    video = params[:video]
    if video
      # Send file to Amazon S3 bucket and grab URL
      uploader = VideoUploader.new
      uploader.store!(video.tempfile)
      # uploader.retrieve_from_store!(tempfile_name)
      # logger.info uploader.download_url(video.original_filename)
    end
  end
```

I've tried carrierwave + fog, fog-aws. When I remove the S3 equation the file will be stored locally (development machine). I am at my wits end with trying lib/ hacks, downgrading versions. I hope its a simple oversight but am out of ideas.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed!** The problem was pretty stupid and man I wish I caught it sooner. The initializer file was in the environments directory (I even listed it in my question!), not the initializers directory... don't code on an empty stomach.

Would be great if the code could detect that missing file... but at least its solved.